# NSwag Post Build swagger.json generation fails

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger-codegen, nswag

I'm generating part of the build the swagger.json, using part of my csproj.

```
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net50) run nswagconfig.nswag /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    </Target>
```

The problem that I have is that the API at runtime is loading the Configuration object from Azure App Configuration like this in my Program.cs :

```
if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(o =>
                    {
                        o.Connect(new Uri(builtConfig["AppConfig:Endpoint"]), new ManagedIdentityCredential())
                            .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                            .Select(KeyFilter.Any, builtConfig["Environment"]);
                    });
                }
```

The `context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` is false at build time, and for some reason, the nswagger generation command is executing the if statement, and uses the Azure App Configuration SDK, which is wrong and out of scope.

What options do I have in this kind of scenario, to achieve the swagger generation, and also dont affect the Configuration object loading based on different environments?

Note: if I change my condition to `if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())` the swagger.json generation works fine

Answer (score 3):

In your `nswag.json` file, set the `aspNetCoreEnvironment` property to "Development".

NSwag will set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to this value before running the generator, and this is one of the environment variables that `context.HostingEnvironment` looks at to determine where it's running.

From the NSwag Studio UI:

[image: NSwag Studio]

Comment: Where is the usage of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT documented? I am not able to find it anywhere.

Comment: @void.pointer Not sure this counts as documentation, but it's explained in the UI of NSwag Studio, which is a GUI you can use to modify nswag.json.